# Convert Hex String to unsigned Char

Tags: c++, string, char, hex

I have something like:

```
string hex = "\x80\x01";
```

and want to convert it to a **unsigned char** like:

```
unsigned char hex_char[] = "\x80\x01";
```

I tried `strcpy` but it won't work since it doesn't support unsigned char

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Why not a simple `char[]`?

Comment: Because I have a function that requires a unsigned char in order to work properly (it's some kind of checksum calculator)

Comment: why not `strcpy((char*)hex_char, ...)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the in-practice you can just copy the values, any way you find natural.

E.g.

```
using Byte = unsigned char;
string hex  = "\x80\x01";
vector<Byte> bytes( hex.begin(), hex.end() );
```

Or if you know that it will always be just two bytes,

```
using Byte = unsigned char;
string hex  = "\x80\x01";
Byte bytes[] = {{ hex[0], hex[1] }};
```

*Formally* it's a different kettle of fish, because with 8-bit byte the value `\x80` won't fit as a positive signed `char` value. So it ends up as an implementation defined value. But in practice this is not a problem because computer evolution has converged on two's complement representation of signed integers, and I don't think there's any C++ compiler that doesn't use it.

Comment: using the <vector> works, but i want to call a function with this and it dosen't support vector
The function looks like this:
`unsigned short crc(unsigned char *  Ptr, unsigned int Len){
}`

Comment: @derbobo33: Simply use the `.data` and `.size` member functions.

Comment: I tried that, but if i print the vector data out, it will look like this:
`\x80\x01²²²²`

Comment: Wait. Are you saying that you are concluding that you can't use a `vector` for your purpose because you can imagine a way to print the contents that will magically render the values as escape sequences and add some garbage at the end? I think this conclusion comes from inspecting things in a debugger. If so then remember that the debugger shows you parts of the `vector`'s buffer that are not in use.

Comment: I got it to work now, i just made a syntax fault. Thank you for your help!